# How to run a rails application as a test environment mode when it is hosted in public domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a rails application running in the production mode at public url.

I need to run the same application in the test environment mode at public url. This is because Payu Payment Gateway asked us to run the application in test environment mode at public url. So that they can perform some server security audits.

I have changed some configurations in the Phusion passenger config file, but I can't get through.

Help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just set an environment variable RAILS_ENV=test . But they are probably asking for an staging environment (where they can mess up with database). The rails env won't matter to them.